# why wont this display correctly listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: c#, user-interface, listbox, selectedindexchanged

first question is how do i get the textboxes to display all of the payroll information for the  employee selected in the list box, I am not sure how to display HourlyWage, Hours, and Salary. second i want the compute pay button to display a paycheck for the currently selected employee in the ListBox control. I am not sure what is wrong with my code and why it is not displaying.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // create list
    private List<Employee> payroll;

    private int count = 0;
    private int SIZE = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        payroll = new List<Employee>(SIZE);

        // Create some employee objects
        payroll.Add(new Hourly(1, "H. Potter", "Privet Drive", "201-9090", 40, 12.00));
        payroll.Add(new Salaried(2, "A. Dumbledore", "Hogewarts", "803-1230", 1200));
        payroll.Add(new Hourly(3, "R. Weasley", "The Burrow", "892-2000", 40, 10.00));
        payroll.Add(new Salaried(4, "R. Hagrid", "Hogwarts", "910-8765", 1000));

        foreach (Employee emp in payroll)
            employeeListBox.Items.Add(emp.Name);


    }


    private void buttonCalcPay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBoxCheck.Clear();
        int index = count;

        if (index < SIZE)
        {
            //The Compute Pay Button: When this button is clicked, display a 
            //paycheck for the currently selected employee in the ListBox 
            //control.

            string ostring = ("Fluffshuffle Electronics               check no.");
            ostring += string.Format("{0}", index);
            ostring += Environment.NewLine;
            ostring += Environment.NewLine;
            ostring += "       pay to the order of";
            ostring += payroll[index].Name;
            ostring += Environment.NewLine;
            ostring += "       ";
            ostring += string.Format("{0:C}", payroll[index].CalcPay());
            ostring += Environment.NewLine;
            ostring += Environment.NewLine;
            ostring += "             First National Bank";
            textBoxCheck.Text = ostring;

            textBoxName.Text = payroll[index].Name;
            textBoxAddress.Text = payroll[index].Address;
            textBoxPhone.Text = payroll[index].PhoneNum;
            textBoxEmpNum.Text = string.Format("{0}", payroll[index].EmpNum);

            //index++;
            //see if object is hourly
            Hourly someEmp1 = payroll[index] as Hourly;
            if (someEmp1 != null)
            {
                textBoxHours.Text = string.Format("{0:F2}", someEmp1.HoursWorked);
                textBoxHourlyWage.Text = string.Format("{0:F2}", someEmp1.HourlyWage);
                textBoxSalary.Clear();

            }
            //not hourly, must be salary
            Salaried someEmp2 = payroll[index] as Salaried;
            if (someEmp2 != null)
            {
                textBoxHours.Clear();
                textBoxHourlyWage.Clear();
                textBoxSalary.Text = string.Format("{0:F2}", someEmp2.Salary);

            }

            else
            {
                buttonCalcPay.Enabled = false;
                textBoxName.Clear();
                textBoxAddress.Clear();
                textBoxEmpNum.Clear();
                textBoxPhone.Clear();
                textBoxHours.Clear();
                textBoxHourlyWage.Clear();
                textBoxSalary.Clear();
                count = 0;
            }

        } count++;
    }
    private void textBoxCheck_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBoxName.Text = payroll[employeeListBox.SelectedIndex].Name;
        textBoxAddress.Text = payroll[employeeListBox.SelectedIndex].Address;
        textBoxEmpNum.Text = string.Format("(0)",payroll[employeeListBox.SelectedIndex].EmpNum);
        textBoxPhone.Text = payroll[employeeListBox.SelectedIndex].PhoneNum;




    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just ran this code, it works. I made a few slight modifications (and simplified your Employee object for quicker results).

I changed the way you assign items to the listbox and used `DataSource` with `DisplayMember` instead. `DataSource` automatically binds your collection to the listbox, and `DisplayMember` tells it which property to use for display. This also means that the `SelectedItem` is actually an `Employee` object you can use.

Also, I changed the way you handle selected items in your events. There is no need to work directly with arrays and indexes, it just gets confusing. You can use the `sender` parameter of your events to know who triggered the listbox change event.

```cs
    // create list
    private List<Employee> payroll;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        payroll = new List<Employee>();

        // Create some employee objects
        payroll.Add(new Employee(1, "H. Potter", "Privet Drive", "201-9090"));
        payroll.Add(new Employee(2, "A. Dumbledore", "Hogewarts", "803-1230"));
        payroll.Add(new Employee(3, "R. Weasley", "The Burrow", "892-2000"));
        payroll.Add(new Employee(4, "R. Hagrid", "Hogwarts", "910-8765"));

        employeeListBox.DataSource = payroll;
        employeeListBox.DisplayMember = "Name";


    }

    private void employeeListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Employee selectedEmployee = ((sender as ListBox).SelectedItem as Employee);
        txtAddress.Text = selectedEmployee.Address;
        txtName.Text = selectedEmployee.Name;
        txtPhone.Text = selectedEmployee.PhoneNum;
    }

    private void btnCalc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Employee selectedEmployee = (employeeListBox.SelectedItem as Employee);

        // Do calculations here...
    }
```

Comment: it is working and its not throwing any errors, however the buttonCalc pay does not work correctly, and i am not sure why?  it wont write in the textboxCheck, or do any calculations

Comment: I'd say that it's because of `if (index < SIZE)`. You declare the `SIZE` to be 0, and I don't see you changing it anywhere. Why do you even need this variable? If you want to know the size of the list, just use `payroll.Count`. However, you don't even need to check this at all. If you check my code, you automatically get the `Employee` object that's been selected and have no need in searching for it or going through indexes of arrays.

Comment: You don't need to increment the size, ever. You're using `List<T>`, it allocates memory dynamically all by itself. You don't need to tell it how big it is on initialization. And if you check my example, you don't need to store any indexes or search your List based on the selection of the list box.